# Voltage behaviour in battery-powered vehicle when motors regenerate

Tags: batteries, brushless-dc-motor, back-emf

I am wondering how the voltage in a battery powered vehicle will behave in case its BLDC motors are acting as generators (i.e. while decelerating). In a system powered with a DC/DC converter for example, the voltage would rise by the amplitude of the back EMF. Would that also be the case if the system is powered by a battery that supports energy recouperation and could thus act as a current sink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the motors act as generators you're exactly correct, the voltage rises based on the speed of the motor and BEMF constant.  If you load the motor as in regenerative braking, you have to have somewhere to put the energy.

Generally, the traction inverter will control the torque, and the input voltage bus to the traction inverter will start to rise in voltage.  That energy (RPM*braking torque-losses) is then used to charge the traction battery, keeping the voltage from rising to a point where it could be destructive.

If there's excess energy over the amount that the batteries can handle, the braking torque has to be reduced, or the energy has to be dissipated somehow. (Electrically as heat or mechanically as heat in the brake rotors.)

Answer (score 1):

The battery voltage will increase slightly due to the current charging the battery, not due to the motor back EMF.

What you are forgetting is that the motor is not connected directly to the battery: there is a motor controller between the battery and the motor. Consequently, the back EMF of the motor is unrelated to the battery voltage.

Normally, the motor voltage is lower than the battery voltage, whether driving or braking.

(As an aside, regen is disabled if the battery is full.)